# PHP and Image Uploads, Display Server Side Errors on same page

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a form, which utilizes uploads.php. See below:

```
<?php
    include 'config/database.php';

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx") {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, DOC, PDF & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    header("Location: http://same-page-the-form-is-on.php");

 ?>
```

The form (index.php):

```
<form id="myForm" action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" id="simple-post" value="Upload File Here" name="submit">
</form>


<?php
            $dir = "uploads/";
            $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
            echo "<select>";
            foreach($files as $item ) {
                echo "<option value='.$item.'>" . $item . "</option>\n";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

So based on what occurs with the upload, whether it be a file already existing, file too big, or wrong file extension, **I want that server-side error message to display on index.php**. What would be the correct way to go about this? AJAX?

Comment: AJAX - it's very good choice, but you also may use redirect with GET to the same page (uploads.php?<key>=<error code>)

Comment: Ahhh that's a great idea. I'll look into that and report back here, thank you!

Comment: You can store the errors in a session variable and redirect back and display those errors that you stored in the session. And then kill the session to prevent displaying the error again.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function that does your server side validation from the Index.php and return the thrown error from that function to that Index.php and echo it out. The function could be fired up if a certain POST variable is set.